German domicile for Germany Patent Application
Any overseas applicants have some suggestions on how to bypass this regulation? Or I have to pay attorney fee to a German attorney?
How will the patent office verify or use this German address? Will they send post mail and office action to this address or just need it to be on the application form?

To clarify - you are looking for a trick to avoid engaging a German patent practitioner so you can attempt to prosecute a patent application via corresponding yourself with the DPMA through the entire process with the result being a valuable patent ?

exactly, you know that attorney fee is too expensive for me, and is there any ways I could apply it myself,
